# GMSPlacePicker not showing the map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, gmsplacepicker

I have integrated GMSPlacePickerConfig for iOS and the place picker is working - so I can see places around me and also search using the auto complete.

The only problem I have at the moment is wi the map which currently only displays the icons without the actual map data (streets etc)

How can enable the map to show more details?

[image: Picket with empty map]

Comment: console gives any error in logs ?

Comment: @Shubhank I have similar problem. Error log says: Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: Although my bundle id and apikey matches. Thanks.

Comment: please ask a new question with the relevant details or search for the error log @Krishanbhag . you will find questions with proper answers for it

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3 - Xcode 10**

For anyone else encountering the same issue, two things:

1. Make sure you put correct GMSService API Key in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the code:

   ```
   GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOURAPIKEY");
   ```
2. Make sure you enable Google Maps SDK for iOS in Google Developers Console

Answer (score 3):

Your problem must be solved now. But still this can help anyone else who might be facing this problem.

We might have not enabled Google Maps SDK Api from Google Developer Console. Try again by enabling that API from Google Console. As I was having the same problem, by enabling from the console shows my maps.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what was missing: The required references to the other frameworks (it was a clean project)

Once I have added the list below the map was loaded:

```
AVFoundation.framework
CoreData.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreText.framework
GLKit.framework
ImageIO.framework
libc++.dylib
libicucore.dylib
libz.dylib
OpenGLES.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to enable Google MAPs from developer portal 
    https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

And Enable it for your platform

Answer (score 0):

```
// Enable Google Places Api in Google Developer Console .
// Use these in App Delegate
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("key")
```

or

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("key")
```